# Android Studio warnings not showing in Inspection Results

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings, review

I seem to get more "yellow warnings" in my code window than I get warnings in my "Inspection Results" window when I run: "Analyse > Inspect Code..."

One such example is: `if (myLayout == null)`

to which the message says: `Condition 'myLayout == null' is always 'false`'

Which is a fair enough warning and worth addressing. How do I get this warning to show up in my "Inspection Results"?

**Edit:** Thank you to @Android_id for the suggestion (since deleted) but that's exactly the thing I can't see:
[image]

**Edit:** To clarify. In particular what I am wanting to understand is why there is a difference between what the code window highlights as a "Yellow warning" and what the "Inspection results" raise as "warnings". I appreciate there (may) be reasons people would want them to show different things but, well, I want them to show the same damn it!

**Additional info:** In my naivety, when I was looking over results before I did click "disable inspection" without realising what it did. While I didn't do this on many results and thought I had undone the action it is possible that it may go some of the way to explaining the discrepancies. Is there a way to check what warnings I have disabled in the inspection results and re-enable them accordingly?